# TEI format vs. SGML format

Tags: sgml, tei

Can anybody explain the difference between [TEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Encoding_Initiative) and [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) format and/or how they are related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short **TEI is XML, XML is SGML**.

The "G" in SGML (Standard **Generalized** [Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)) means (among several other things) that a markup language may customize it *syntax*. For instance, you can define an SGML syntax where the tags (or elements) are like `[v id:id1]` instead of `<v id="id1"></v>`.

XML is a concrete syntax of SGML, plus several other requirements that subset SGML. In XML (and HTML too) the elements are delimited by angular brackets: `<body>`. Each tag in XML must be paired with an explicit end tag: `</body>`.

So far, we haven't talk about how the document is structured (the document type or schema). XML by itself does not impose restrictions on the document structure. The following is valid (i.e. well-formed) XML:

```
<item>
   <body>
     <head>I don't know what I'm doing</head>
   </body>
</item>
```

TEI defines a common structure that all TEI documents must comply with, and assign a meaning to each tag. For instance:

> The actual text (`<text>`) contains a single text of any kind. This
>   commonly contains the actual text and other encodings. A text `<text>`
>   minimally contains a text body (`<body>`). The body contains lower-level
>   text structures like paragraphs (`<p>`), or different structures for
>   text genres other than prose [[source](http://tei.oucs.ox.ac.uk/GettingStarted/html/in.html)]

```
<text>
  <body>
    <p>For the first time in twenty-five years...</p>
  </body>
</text>
```